Oracle SQL : different where clauses with respect to the different variables in a single clause



CATEGORY
DATE(DD.MM.YYYY)




a
01.01.2024


a
02.01.2024


a
03.01.2024


a
04.01.2024


a
05.01.2024


b
01.01.2024


b
10.01.2024


b
15.01.2024


c
01.01.2024


c
11.01.2024


c
25.01.2024



I am trying to get the below in a single query:



CATEGORY
DATE(DD.MM.YYYY)




a
01.01.2024


a
02.01.2024


a
03.01.2024


a
04.01.2024


a
05.01.2024


b
10.01.2024


b
15.01.2024


c
25.01.2024



Rougly something like if CATEGORY = a then DATE >= 01.01.2024
                                    CATEGORY = b then DATE \>=10.01.2024

                                    CATEGORY = c then DATE \>=25.01.2024

                                    .

                                    .

                                    .

I am working with a data sets over 300k+ rows and over 10k+ distinct CATEGORY variables and I have a seperate excel file that contains CATEGORY variables and the DATE variables corresponding to the CATEGORY variables. Something like below:



CATEGORY
DATE




a
01.01.2024


b
10.01.2024


c
25.01.2024



Is it possible to do so? Thank you for your contribution and time.

Please have a look, if you need something like this https://dbfiddle.uk/9O3J8Z9j

That definitely helps, thank you.

use AND and OR:
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  (category = 'a' AND date_column >= DATE '2024-01-01')
OR     (category = 'b' AND date_column >= DATE '2024-01-10')
OR     (category = 'c' AND date_column >= DATE '2024-01-25')

or, use a CASE expression in the WHERE clause:
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  date_column >= CASE category
                      WHEN 'a' THEN DATE '2024-01-01'
                      WHEN 'b' THEN DATE '2024-01-10'
                      WHEN 'c' THEN DATE '2024-01-25'
                      ELSE NULL
                      END

If you have lots of categories then load your data into a table and filter using that table:
SELECT *
FROM   table_name t
EXISTS (SELECT 1
        FROM   your_loaded_data yld
        WHERE  t.category    =  yld.category
        AND    t.date_column >= yld.date_column)


If you could load your excel category dates into a database table you could use Inner Join as a filter.
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    table_name (CATEGORY,   A_DATE) AS
        ( Select 'a', DATE '2024-01-01' From Dual Union All 
          Select 'a',   DATE '2024-01-02' From Dual Union All 
          Select 'a',   DATE '2024-01-03' From Dual Union All 
          Select 'a',   DATE '2024-01-04' From Dual Union All 
          Select 'a',   DATE '2024-01-05' From Dual Union All 
          Select 'b',   DATE '2024-01-01' From Dual Union All 
          Select 'b',   DATE '2024-01-10' From Dual Union All 
          Select 'b',   DATE '2024-01-15' From Dual Union All 
          Select 'c',   DATE '2024-01-01' From Dual Union All 
          Select 'c',   DATE '2024-01-11' From Dual Union All 
          Select 'c',   DATE '2024-01-25' From Dual 
        ), 
      --  L o a d e d   E x c e l    D a t a :
    excel_category_dates (CATEGORY, FROM_DATE) AS
        ( Select 'a', DATE '2024-01-01' From Dual Union All
          Select 'b', DATE '2024-01-10' From Dual Union All
          Select 'c', DATE '2024-01-25' From Dual 
        )

--    S Q L :
SELECT      t.*
FROM        table_name t
INNER JOIN  excel_category_dates cd ON(cd.CATEGORY = t.CATEGORY And t.A_DATE >= cd.FROM_DATE)

/*    R e s u l t :
CATEGORY  A_DATE  
--------  --------
a         01.01.24
a         02.01.24
a         03.01.24
a         04.01.24
a         05.01.24
b         10.01.24
b         15.01.24
c         25.01.24    */

